# how to make official Facebook unity plugin work friendly with prime31 unity plugins

Tags: facebook, plugins, unity-game-engine, prime31

As far as I know, if I choose official facebook unity plugin, then a few prime31 unity plugins for android would be broken because they all override the main Unity Activity. Because there are many prime31 plugins but only one official facebook plugin, so an ideal solution would be that only changes to facebook plugin is applied.

The question is: how? Does anyone have experience on this?

Best,

Raven

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a bit old but no one has answered. You can use facebook with prime31's other plugins but you need a small modification to the FacebookPostProcess.cs ( changing a line from some default to 9999 ). I've ran into this issue twice, once for developing an app and another for a game. It has worked both times. Heres the official documentation: http://prime31.com/docs ( the red text box at the top ) and https://gist.github.com/prime31/6417808 for the code for implementation. Hope this helps.